# Testing automation tool

Tags: software-testing

We have a couple of use cases for functional test automation. We are also looking for mobile, API testing, database testing along with Jenkins integration.

We explored Selenium X/web driver/IDE/Grid, but one or the other use case is not satisfied. Our primary goal is to find a tool which needs less amount of scripting/coding.

So any fist hand experience on tools like TestingWhiz or QTP?

Some of the uses cases are:

1.Data driven testing

2.Selection of multiple checkboxes/radio buttons/multiplevalues from drop-down

3.Provision of conditional statements

4.CBC

Comment: Please specify what your requirements are in terms of cost and open source vs. closed source. Also are you open to using more that one tool? Your requirements cover a lot of different aspects of testing so it would be difficult to find one tool that does all of them effectively.

Comment: We r ok for open source or product. More then one tool seems bit difficult at t moment. Though we r ok for hybrid approach i.e scripting & code-less combo. We want to have CBC, jenkins integration

Comment: Automated testing is very technology specific. Do you have C#, Java, C++, HTML? As it stands now, the question can hardly be answered.

Comment: Few updates, we are evaluating TestingWhiz  for web, mobile platforms. It appears to fit our use cases along with jenkins integrations. Will update more once we actually zero down on something. Thanks All!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how much scripting/coding you are happy to make. **[Stamp](https://stamp.ow2.org/bin/view/main/)** is an open source project that may give you ideas:

Multiple solutions have been combined to create a testing platform. From what I gathered [here](https://stamp.ow2.org/bin/view/main/overview), the take aways are: the ability to deploy multiple environment with different configuration type to increase your range of tested scenarios.

More precisely: STAMP will complete the Jenkins, or other CI/CD tools by providing test amplification tools, performance tests are considered as on-line (runtime) tests.

To relate to your request, more scenarios of configuration will be tested with this method. You'll also check your API performances.

Sorry I am not familiar enough with the project to share more. I thought it could be of interest since the traditional tools are not satisfying you.

Comment: what is it about?

Comment: Multiple solutions have been combined to create a testing platform. From what I gathered [here](https://stamp.ow2.org/bin/view/main/overview), the take aways are: the ability to deploy multiple environment with different configuration type to increase your range of tested scenarios. I know people from the team if you would like more information.

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! This post does not contain enough information to be considered an answer. Please [read our discussion on what makes an answer high quality](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/356/185) to see if you can incorporate some of these improvements into your answer. Especially, answers must point out how the product meets the requirements, and what makes it recommendable (preferably personal experience). I'm integrating your last comment now; please [edit] your post again to fill the other gaps. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It seems I'm a bit late to the party but still I would add it here so it can help someone coming to this thread looking for recommendations.

So, as far as the requirements goes,

- functional test automation for mobile, API testing, database testing
  along with Jenkins integration
- a tool which needs less amount of scripting/coding
- Data driven testing Selection of multiple
- checkboxes/radio buttons/multiplevalues from drop-down
- Provision of conditional statements
- CBC

As of now, we have codeless Tools in the market that covers all of the requirements stated by the OP. One of those tools is [Testsigma](https://wwww.testsigma.com) and I'm one of the core team members.

All of the above requirements are met in Testsigma. You may check out [Testsigma features](https://testsigma.com/features) to know more.